# why post categories are not included in API of Strapi?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi, headless-cms

I've made these content types : **post** and **category**
and category has a `many-to-many` relation to post content type. buy I can't get each post category via API!

[image: Text]
API URL I use to get all posts :

```
ALL_POSTS = "http://192.168.242.80:4001/api/posts/"
```

response type I get :

```
{
   "data":{
      "id":5,
      "attributes":{
         "title":"",
         "description"",
         "tag":"",
         "slug":"",
         "createdAt":"2023-03-15T05:39:04.763Z",
         "updatedAt":"2023-03-25T08:19:32.682Z",
         "publishedAt":"2023-03-15T05:39:05.953Z"
      }
   },
   "meta":{
      
   }
```

as you see , category of the posts are not included! just **tag** field is included but tag is an **enumeration** field that is not suitable for my purpose
[image: Text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do that, we need to `populate` relations. check the link bellow and read the *Strapi doc* about populations:
https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest/populate-select#populate-1-level-for-all-relations

using these kind of queries will help:

```
GET /api/articles?populate=*
```